# Send data with HTTP delete method

Tags: php, gwt, http-method

Is it possible to send data with the HTTP delete method because when I'm trying to send data with GWT request builder, on the server, it not finding the data!!

Comment: Please post some code examples so we can see what you are doing and possibly help you.

Comment: Aside from an identifier for the item to be deleted I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/1.1 does not define the meaning of the request payload for the `DELETE` method: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7 so it might be that the browser removes it before sending the request.

HTTPbis (the revision of HTTP/1.1) adds some precision, in that it explicitly says that it doesn't define the meaning of the request payload: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-17#section-6.7

All in all, GWT doesn't do anything special. If you're experiencing an unexpected behavior, it's probably your browser (or possibly a network intermediary).